Is `mydict.get(x, x)` eqivalent to `mydict.get(x) or x`?
When using a dictionary to occasionally replace values, are .get(x, x) and .get(x) or x equivalent?
For example:
def current_brand(brand_name):
    rebrands = {
        "Marathon":    "Snickers",
        "Opal Fruits": "Starburst",
        "Jif":         "Cif",
        "Thomson":     "TUI",
    }
    
    return rebrands.get(brand_name, brand_name)
    # or
    return rebrands.get(brand_name) or brand_name

    # this is forbidden - cannot use `default` keyword argument here
    return rebrands.get(brand_name, default=brand_name)

assert current_brand("Jif") == "Cif"
assert current_brand("Boots") == "Boots"

I think .get(x) or x is clearer, but that's pretty much a matter of opinion, so I'm curious if there's a technical benefit or drawback to one or the other I've not spotted.
Edit: sorry, to be clear, I'm assuming that the dictionary does not contain falsey values as that would't make sense in this context (i.e. in the example above you're not recording that "Somerfield" rebranded as "")

They produce different results if x is present in the dict, but the corresponding value is "falsy" - 0, for example.

Mildly deeper dive into how dict.get is implemented here.

.get(x, x) would really be more idiomatic, IMO, and the semantics more straightforward

In answer to your original question: or will short-circuit if your value is Falsey, so there are plenty of values where the two statements will behave differently.
my_dict = {
    'foo': 0,
    'bar': "",
    'baz': [],
}

x = 'foo'
print(repr(my_dict.get(x, x)))
print(repr(my_dict.get(x) or x))

In answer to your edit, if you can guarantee that your dict is definitely a dict, and that the values in your dict are always Truthy, then the two should behave equivalently.
There may be some performance tradeoffs either way, but I generally don't bother to get hung up on that. In my opinion the downside of your method is philosophical. To my eyes, .get(x, ...) communicates your intent as "retrieve key x, and if it's not there, default to ...". .get(x) or ... communicates "if it's not there, or is defined as a Falsey value, default to ...". The intent displayed in your question suggests you should use .get(x, x), but for a simple example like this it hardly matters.

Yes, thanks, I see your point and would now prefer .get(x, x) as a result. In this string substitution example it's likely the replacement values are not gonna be empty strings but in other concepts a valid replacement could be falsey, so .get(x, x) is the way to go!

In the case there are never falsy values in the dictionary or x, the two options have the same output, but get(x, x) is better than get(x) or x because get(x, x) is simpler, more explicit, more obvious, and more readable (especially for someone who might not know the dict can never contain falsy values). It might also be faster; the two functions involve exactly the same operations except the second one has an extra operation.
import dis
dis.dis(lambda: rebrands.get("Marathon", "Marathon"))  # 8 operations
dis.dis(lambda: rebrands.get("Marathon") or "Marathon")) # 9 operations


"number of operations" is not a good indicator of performance. Different operators can take a lot more time than others, especially function calls
